# I can not open a spesific vue project on Control panel either VS code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vuetify.js

i try to open a vue project already exist but i can't do this. I already try npm commands like npm install, npm run serve, npm build, but still doesn't work. Can you help me?
[This is error screen on terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSB3Z.png)

```
npm install
npm install --force
npm run serve
//still doesn't work
```

Comment: there's not enough information here to help.  your error screenshot is cropped too small.  avoid screenshots, please paste the entire error in a code snippet.  not sure what command you ran to get the error either.  also paste the `package.json` contents.  if it's a public repo you can share that would also be very helpful.

Comment: That error usually indicates mismatching node version, like stated above, provide `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for help guys, i solved problem with decrease my node.js version 16 to 14.